# Issue a message to user that isnt from application

Tags: c#, winforms

We have two applications.

1. Main.exe - which is the main application being updated
2. Update.exe - the program that runs to update Main.exe

My problem is preventing users from getting into the main.exe while updating.

Right now, I am checking for a flag file and if the flag file exists, application.exe immediately.

This is fine except it doesn't tell the user anything, just kicks them out.

I were to issue a message, the time that it takes for them to respond to the message, the main.exe is in use and cannot be updated.

Any suggestions how I can professionally display a message that the update is in progress, application closing?

btw, I thought about using:

```
Private Function IsUpdatingPropane() As Boolean
    Try
        Dim UpdateInprocess As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetParentPath(Application.StartupPath) & "\update.inprocess"
        If File.Exists(UpdateInprocess) Then

            'Dim Proc As Process
            'Dim ProcInfo As New ProcessStartInfo(Configuration.DataFileLocations & Configuration.GasLibrary & "\vbmsg.exe")
            'ProcInfo.Arguments = String.Format("vbmsg.txt,{0},{1},NIL,NIL,NIL,OK,9996,9997", Configuration.UserId, Configuration.WorkstationId)
            'ProcInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
            'ProcInfo.WorkingDirectory = Configuration.DataFileLocations & Configuration.GasLibrary
            'ProcInfo.UseShellExecute = False
            'Proc = Process.Start(ProcInfo)


            Application.Exit()
            Return True
        End If
        Return False
    Catch ex As Exception
        WriteException(ex)
        WriteDebugInfo("VerifyNotUpdatingPropane", "An error occurred while checking for update.inprocess file. Please contact SSS for assistance.", True, ex)
        Return True
    End Try
End Function
```

but what do I call to display the message?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not very clear what you're *exactly* asking for: how to show the message, or how implement exe locking in better way?

Comment: how to display a message that you cannot run the main.exe without locking up the program keeping it from updating

Comment: Need more information, such as what API/Framework are you working with (WPF, WinForms, etc)? Maybe a code example of what your trying to do. From what it sounds so far, could you not just display a message box of some form when you determine some flag file exists?

Comment: sry I updated it, I'm using winforms and I added the code. If I dispay a messagebox the main.exe will remain open until the user clicks ok, thus the update.exe might conflict with a file in use. Right now I am just closing the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the data we have

1. Main.exe
2. Updater.exe

On update request from `Main.exe` the `Main.exe` launches `Updater.exe` end kills itself. 
`Updater.exe` does it stuff. To resolving notification problem in case when user clicks on `Main.exe` again you can, for example, launch the second instance of `Updater.exe` with some special parameter, which actualy diplays a message and exit from `Main.exe`.  In this case even if user will not close the notification dialog box for a while (cofee pause), you will have contemporary in memory **2** instances of `Updater.exe`. One is updating, the second simply shows the message and one time message closed leaves the memory.

In short, move message visualization inside `Updater.exe` itself, which appears only in case of presence of special command line parameter.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This might work. I am copying the update.exe to update_old.exe so that the original update.exe can be updated... so, I could call the update_old.exe and have it display a message. I think that might just work.  Ty!

Comment: if you want to update Updater itself, just download a new version of it. I mean on update request: Main can first download a new version of Updater (if any), after launch it. In short Main can take care of updating Updater to the latest version. But all depends on your architecture.

Answer (score 1):

There are several possible solutions to this problem, including:

1. Create a simple bootstrap application which checks for the flag file and if it doesn't exist then launch the main.exe. Otherwise prompt the user with your error. This only works if you never have to update the boostrapper.
2. Use AppDomain shadow copy to allow your users access to your application while it is updating then once it is finished prompt them to restart and the updated files will overwrite the "active" ones.

Comment: I am checking out AppDomain shadow copy now, although for a quick solution I am going to use the update.exe displaying the message. I will look at doing this once I have it resolved in the more crude way.